# How do I bind keys in ido?

Tags: key-bindings, ido, projectile, flx-ido

I'm trying [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) + [`ido`](http://www.emacswiki.org/InteractivelyDoThings) + [`flx-ido`](https://github.com/lewang/flx/blob/master/flx-ido.el) (just for Projectile, `ido-mode` disabled otherwise).

But: I don't like using <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> to switch between items. I want to change them into <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd>, but have been unsuccessful:

```
(define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<down>") 'ido-next-match)
(define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<up>") 'ido-prev-match)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "<down>") 'ido-next-match)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "<up>") 'ido-prev-match)
```

My question, therefore, is: **How do I bind keys in `ido-mode`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the source code, you need to modify keybindings via `ido-setup-hook`:

```
;; Customization
;; -------------
;;
;; Customize the `ido' group to change the `ido' functionality.
;;
;; To modify the keybindings, use the ido-setup-hook.  For example:
;;(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)
;;
;;(defun ido-my-keys ()
;;  "Add my keybindings for ido."
;;  (define-key ido-completion-map " " 'ido-next-match)
;;  )
```

So do the following:

```
(defun bind-ido-keys ()
  "Keybindings for ido mode."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "<down>") 'ido-next-match) 
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "<up>")   'ido-prev-match))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook #'bind-ido-keys)
```