# How to disable keybinding (`\C-o`) in ido-find-file?

Tags: key-bindings, ido

I want to disable key-binding `\C-o` on `ido-find-file`. If I press it generates `^J` and completion does not completed so I want to disable it.

I have tried following but it did not work.

```
(defun ido-common-completion-map ()
  "Add my keybindings for Ido."
  (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") 'nil))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook #'ido-common-completion-map)
```

---

I have followed for [ido-wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode)  and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3730/18414

> ```
> (defun ido-disable-line-truncation ()
>   (set (make-local-variable 'truncate-lines) nil))
> (add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook #'ido-disable-line-truncation)
> (defun ido-define-keys () ;; C-n/p is more intuitive in vertical layout
>   (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-n") 'ido-next-match)
>   (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-p") 'ido-prev-match))
> (add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-define-keys)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow same approach which I mention in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55607/8426

call    `helpful-function` `ido-find-file`

It opens clickable bufferm In this buffer, you have to click `C-o` than you will learn which key-map that you are interacting.

Next screen after click will tell you which in which map that you have to change.

Big possible answer is for you(This keybinding somehow was not defined in my emacs I am not sure):

```
(define-key ido-buffer-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") nil)
(define-key ido-file-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

That key is defined on `ido-file-completion-map`.

Comment: You might want to expand a bit for the benefit of those readers for whom the implications of what you say aren't obvious.

Comment: I have tired `(defun ido-common-completion-map ()
  "Add my keybindings for Ido."
  (define-key ido-file-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") 'nil))` which did not work as well @db48x

Comment: Try to simplify your configuration by getting rid of the hook. Just put `(define-key ido-file-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") 'nil))` alone into your init file. You can also debug this by putting `(lookup-key ido-file-completion-map (kbd "\C-o"))` into your `*scratch*` buffer, then typing `C-x e` to run it. By default it'll return `ido-copy-current-word`, but if you've successfully rebound the key, it'll return what you rebound it to.